# Translate and understand buttons in the translation file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this pipe

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private dom: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(value) {
        return this.dom.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value);
    }
}
```

In my html I do :

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    <div [innerHtml]="bodyContent | safeHtml"></div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

In the .ts file :

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.bodyContent = this.translateService.instant('dialog.upgrade_package_requested',
{
   context: `${this.translateService.instant('dialog.context')}`,
   name: `Yuhu`
});
```

My key in translation file :

```
"upgrade_package_requested": "<p> Yuhuu <b>{{context}}</b>.<br /> Name <b>{{name}}</b>.</p><button mat-flat-button>Test</button>",
```

The result is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m4vN.png)

So the button is not interpreted as a button but as a simple text. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance. Any ideas ?

Comment: What if you remove the directive `mat-flat-button`? Does it affect?

Comment: No, the same @callback

Comment: But I get in console this message : `WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see http://g.co/ng/security#xss`

Comment: Have you tried https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml ?

Comment: From what I saw is not safe to use

Comment: Yes it definitely is not safe, but I am just wondering if it is necessary with the `mat-flat-button`. We are just debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `sanitize`, use the [`bypassSecurityTrustHtml`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml) method of the `DomSanitizer`. Since the `button` is the unsafe part that needs to be marked explicitly

Eg:

```
transform(value) {
        return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
```

Check [StackBlitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psd1hs).

**Note** : Calling `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` does come with a caveat. As per Angular docs -

> Calling any of the bypassSecurityTrust... APIs disables Angular's
>   built-in sanitization for the value passed in. Carefully check and
>   audit all values and code paths going into this call. Make sure any
>   user data is appropriately escaped for this security context.

Check more [documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)